# Is it possible for the application developed in xamarin.android to run in windows ce 6.0?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019, windows-ce

I have developed barcode scan application in VS 2019 Pro with Xamarin.Android.

The client wants to use this application in terminal which is Newland Pt-60.

Is there any way to run the this application in Windows CE 6.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Xamarin has never supported Windows CE.  Windows CE was last updated  **SEVEN** years ago, and all versions reached EOL in 2020.

Comment: Thats not correct. The last CE update was released in June 2020 but EOL of Windows CE 2013 will bei in 2028. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/windows_ce/windows-ce-migration-faq



EOL of Windows CE 7.0 was at 13. April 2021 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/end-of-support/end-of-support-2021